# How to close a php page in specific time?

Tags: php, time

I want to close a php page in 20 minutes after it was opened. Actual time is stored in mysql table.

It should display remaining time in page and the page should be closed after 0 of remaining time.

Comment: You realise that PHP is server-side, right?

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing you'd use javascript for.

Comment: Use AlienWebguy's code, and you can dynamically put the time with PHP. Such as `window.setTimeout(self.close, <?php echo $row['time']; ?>);`.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will send the headers out immediately. Just use JavaScript :

```
window.setTimeout(self.close, 1200000);
```